# How is $(\log n)!$ a member of $\theta (\log n \log\log n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

Can you please explain how $(\log n)! = \theta((\log n)*(\log \log n))$? I myself used the equation $n! = \theta(n^n)$ and replaced $\log n$ for $n$ as below
$(\log n)! = \theta((\log(n))^{\log(n)})$. But it is different. Why shouldn't we use this equation?

Comment: Here are tips on [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and on [How to use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Many thanks dear Anthony!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to following @Anthony's advice, notice the following:
$$
f_n = \Theta(g_n) \Rightarrow \\
(1) \lim_n |\frac{f_n}{g_n}| \geq c >0 \\
(2) \lim_n |\frac{f_n}{g_n}| \leq c < \infty 
$$
Both of these conditions must fulfill, otherwise you have different orders. Also notice,
$$
(\log n)! = \prod_{k=2}^n \log k  = e^{\sum_{k=2}^{n} \log \log k} \geq e^{\int_{2}^{n}\log \log x dx}
$$
For this integral, after a bit of algebra, you get
$$
n \log \log n - \int_{2}^{\log n}\frac{e^t dt}{t}
$$
The second integral is an Exponential integral, you should find the solution yourself, but, given the upper bound, it should $\Theta(n)$. Can you handle from here?

Comment: Excellent explanation, many, many thanks dear Alex!!!  But sorry from what you've earned $(logn)!$ is \theta(n*loglogn) not (logn*loglogn), no?

Comment: You should find the asymptotic bounds on the exponential integral up to some order, then just compare the expression you get to the $\log n \log \log n$ by taking the limit of the ratio, since for $n>N$ for some $N$ both expressions are positive

Comment: Many, many thanks dear Alex for all your help!!!! Much appreciated!!! I have forgotten integrals I should read them again.